# Can I run an exit relay through a VPN service?

Tags: exit-relays, vpn

Is it possible to run an exit relay through a VPN service? As long as the service provider has approved this, is it otherwise workable? Do any technical limitations or performance disadvantages make this unworkable? Assuming that there's adequate bandwidth, is the increased latency problematic?

Comment: I did invite Crypto privately to Tor beta, so I'm going to put this question on hold for a few days.

Comment: Crypto isn't interested, so I'll just update the question and answer as more information becomes available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this if your VPN provider allows it, however it seems like would de-anonymize your traffic as all exit traffic would be linked to you (if it's your VPN.) You of course could argue that you were running a relay so the traffic isn't yours, etc.

Now if you're asking if you can connect to your VPN via tor, then this is very bad unless the VPN has nothing to link you to it, like a credit card, etc.

Comment: Well, wherever you run an exit relay, traffic will be linked to you, unless the relay is hosted anonymously. If the VPN provider has agreed, and understands what they've agreed to, there's at least a chance that they'll take the heat. But the same could be said for providers that host exit relays. Also, with the VPN approach, it is true that exit traffic traverses your computer through the VPN, instead of merely traversing a remote server that you're renting. Maybe that's a fatal flaw.

Comment: I wasn't asking here about routing a VPN service through Tor. But I have done that. The most secure way is with free SecurityKISS accounts. More risky is using VPN services purchased with Bitcoins that have been transferred through multiple mixing services from successive Multibit wallets in Whonix instances, with taint checked at https://blockchain.info.

Comment: It seems from [the "More Questions" thread of tor-talk](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-October/030519.html) that Crypto is doing this. I'll add comments, or perhaps an answer, as additional information becomes available.